# Rails "No route matches" error when trying to POST via AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am building a rails app that lets users vote on questions and answers, which are nested:

This code works as intended to let users vote up an answer:

```
<%= link_to raw('<i class="icon-2x icon-chevron-up"></i>'), vote_question_answer_path(@question, answer, :type => :up), :method => :post %>
```

but this code, which should do the same thing via ajax:

```
<%= link_to raw('<i class="icon-2x icon-chevron-up"></i>'), vote_question_answer_path(@question, answer, :type => :up), :remote => true, :method => :post %>
```

records the vote correctly, but then gives the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError at /questions/fugiat-nulla-blue-bottle-raw-denim-fap-sint-butcher-ethical-cosby-sweater-thundercats-distillery-laboris-tofu/answers/6/vote=========================================================================================================================================================================> No route matches {:action=>"vote", :controller=>"answers", :type=>:up, :question_id=>nil, :id=>#<Answer id: 6, body: "Ullamco Pinterest food truck incididunt trust fund,...", user_id: 1, question_id: 10, created_at: "2013-09-10 22:20:40", updated_at: "2013-09-10 22:20:40">}app/views/shared/_vote_answer_arrows.html.erb, line 6
```

I'm confused - aren't the two posting to the same route? Why is one working and the other giving a routing error?

I believe that the problem is related to the nested routes, because I have nearly identical code for the questions, and the AJAX route works there.

EDIT: As requested, here are the relevant routes:

```
resources :questions do
  member { post :vote }
  resources :answers do
    member { post :vote }
  end
end
```

And the respond_to do |format|

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html{ redirect_to :back, :flash => { :success => 'Thank you for voting!' }}
  format.js {}
end
```

Here is the AJAX error message/URL from firebug:

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:3000/questions/fugiat-nulla-blue-bottle-raw-denim-fap-sint-butcher-ethical-cosby-sweater-thundercats-distillery-laboris-tofu/answers/5/vote?type=down"
```

And here is AJAX params from firebug (This looks very wrong to me, so I am not sure if it is the source of the problem or just me being unfamiliar with firebug:

```
type    down
```

And here is a successful non-AJAX request's parameters from the server output:

```
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"X3Dg3TSZ8blMNTT1Zce2R0A1rtZI93ViFJNsjOP145w=", "type"=>"up", "question_id"=>"fugiat-nulla-blue-bottle-raw-denim-fap-sint-butcher-ethical-cosby-sweater-thundercats-distillery-laboris-tofu", "id"=>"3"}
```

Comment: It's interesting that the error message says `No route matches { ... :question_id=>nil, :id=>#<Answer id: 6,...} ...` because 1. the question_id is nil and 2. because the id is an answer **object**. Could you please post your routes.rb file, what a successful request's (when you don't use ajax) parameters are in the rails server output, and what the ajax request's url and parameters are (from firebug or the chrome developer tools)?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I just posted the information you requested. In particular the AJAX params look wrong to me though. I just started using firebug this morning, so I may be looking in the wrong place for the params.

Comment: I just noticed that you said the ajax request "records the vote correctly, but then gives the following error:" So that means the ajax request IS getting routed correctly and getting to your controller action, and the routing error is happening in something that happens AFTER your controller action is processed. What do you do when this request is complete? I see that you have `format.js{}` in your respond_to block; are you doing anything in your javascript after this request completes? Thank you for posting the additional information, that was very helpful in ruling some things out.

Comment: ahhh I see-- the routing error is coming from "app/views/shared/_vote_answer_arrows.html.erb, line 6" - so the error is when rails is trying to render that partial, not when it's trying to process the request! what do you have at that line and what are the values of the variables getting used on that line?

Comment: Your comment led me in the right direction to fix this one, so thank you! In my controller, I had not defined @question. This was not a problem until I turned the request into ajax and needed the variable to render the partials in my javascript.

Comment: woo! you should write this as an answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments above, this turned out to be a simple controller issue.

In my controller, I had not defined @question. This was not a problem until I turned the request into ajax and needed the variable to render the partials in my javascript.

I added

```
@question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
```

to the controller, and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

In your controller do you have a `respond_to do |format|` block?

You should have something like...

```
respond_to do |format|
  if something_saves or whatever
    format.html { redirect_to random_path, notice: 'Vote was casted.' }
    format.json { render :json => { :voteCasted => true } }
  else
    format.html { render :nothing }
  end
end
```

The main line there is the...

```
format.json { render :json => { :voteCasted => true } }
```

At the moment it sounds like you're missing responding to the JSON format. Which is why the HTML version is working fine and the AJAX (JSON) method is not.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the routing error he is receiving.  Rather, it tells the controller what to return to the client (html, json, etc), which doesn't matter if he isn't able to get to the controller in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I do have a format.js line, which is working for the non-nested resource (questions). I added it to the original question.

Comment: Ah ok sorry. Thank you for clarifying.